# How to join only on the row where certain columns are not null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this task. I know of lots of ways to get it to do what I want with either doing something in the where clause or making a subquery, but I do not know which way is the best.

I have this simple query (my real query is much more complex so that is why this is important but the question only pertains to this part):

```
select s.Item_Number
,sr.Royalty_Code
,rc.Royalty_Percentage
,rc.From_Date
,rc.To_Date
--,* 
from Style S 

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Style_Royalty SR WITH (NOLOCK)        
                                    on S.Company_Code = SR.Company_Code
                                    and S.Division_Code = SR.Division_Code
                                    and S.Item_Number = SR.Item_Number
                                    and S.Color_Code = SR.Color_Code

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Royalty_By_Customer RC WITH (NOLOCK)  
                                    on S.Company_Code = RC.Company_Code
                                    and S.Division_Code = RC.Division_Code
                                    and SR.Royalty_Code = RC.Royalty_Code
                                    and RC.Customer_Number ='ecom2x'

where S.Item_Number = '910B1976NSZ'
```

This is what the result looks like

```
+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|   Item_Number   | Royalty_Code | Royalty_Percentage |        From_Date        |         To_Date         |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 910B1976NSZ     | LOONEY       | 10.00              | NULL                    | NULL                    |
| 910B1976NSZ     | LOONEY       | 14.00              | 2016-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2099-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

What is the most efficient way to make it ignore the rows with the NULL From and To Dates? Do I just do where RC.From_Date after my joins is not null or do I select for all the non null rows and then only left join that? Or maybe is there a way to do it directly in the join without using a subquery?

Is this an efficient way to solve the problem?

```
LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Royalty_By_Customer RC WITH (NOLOCK)  
                                        on S.Company_Code = RC.Company_Code
                                        and S.Division_Code = RC.Division_Code
                                        and SR.Royalty_Code = RC.Royalty_Code
                                        and O.Customer_Number = RC.Customer_Number
                                        and RC.From_Date < O.Date_Entered
                                        and RC.To_Date > O.Date_Entered
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind:

```
where rc.from_date is not null and rc_to_date is not null
```

However, the `NULL` values are probably being created by the `LEFT JOIN`s.  I would suggest replacing them with `INNER JOIN`.

If the `NULL` values are in the original table, then both change the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` and add the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: No, the null values are in the original RC table. So it is better to do in the where clause then directly in the join?

Comment: I have seen significant improvements in performance by moving the filter from an INNER JOIN condition to the WHERE clause, even though more frequently the query plan is exactly the same.  Sometimes a add a redundant filter just to see if it changes the query plan.

Comment: @nathan: Yes, you will perform fewer joins.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the filter in your join statement, which should narrow down the results from the second table.

```
LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Royalty_By_Customer RC WITH (NOLOCK)  
                                    on S.Company_Code = RC.Company_Code
                                    and S.Division_Code = RC.Division_Code
                                    and SR.Royalty_Code = RC.Royalty_Code
                                    and RC.Customer_Number ='ecom2x'
                                    and RC.From_Date is not null
                                    and RC.To_Date is not null
```

Comment: Yep I just thought of that right now. Do you know if that is better or worse than doing it in the where clause ? Or does it not make a difference

Comment: Logically, it makes more sense to do it in the join because you'll have fewer records to join between the two tables. However, SQL Server does what SQL Server wants (most Databases do).  Try it both ways and use which one performs better. You may find that as more data is added to the tables, your results may change.  However, if you're filtering on various fields, make sure you have the correct indexes.  I think the actual execution plan gives hints as to what indexes will help it increase performance.